# Como instalar modulos en python sin usar pip

Tags: python

Como puedo realizar la instalacion de modulos sin utilizar pip?

Esto se debe a que estoy en una red con acceso restringido y no puedo realizarlo con pip alguna forma de instalar de forma manual?

Por ejemplo el modulo Pymssql utilizo python 3.7.3

Comment: `pip` puede usarse para instalar también un paquete local que ya tengas descargado, pero cuidado porque en la mayoría de las ocasiones, un paquete necesita de otros para funcionar. Normalmente `pip` se ocupa de instalar también las dependencias, pero si no tienes acceso a la red deberías instalarlas antes tú a mano. Estas dependencias están listadas normalmente en un archivo `setup.py`.

Comment: Otra solución (que posiblemente sea matar moscas a cañonazos) es preparar en una máquina que tenga acceso a la red una imagen docker con todo lo que necesites. Una vez compruebes que todo funciona bien en el contenedor, puedes exportar la imagen a un archivo `.tar.gz`, llevarla a la máquina de acceso restringido, importar la imagen allí en docker (necesitas tener instalado docker), y usarla para instanciar un contenedor que ya tendría todas las dependencias instaladas y la versión de python correcta.

Answer (score 3):

1. Descargue el paquete
2. descomprímalo si está comprimido
3. cd en el directorio que contiene setup.py
4. Si hay instrucciones de instalación contenidas en la documentación aquí contenida, lea y siga las instrucciones
   DE OTRA MANERA
5. escriba `python setup.py install`

Es posible que necesite privilegios de administrador para el paso 5. Lo que haga aquí, por lo tanto, depende de su sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, en Ubuntu, diría `sudo python setup.py install`

Para evitar la necesidad de privilegios de administrador durante el paso 5 anterior, puede utilizar el indicador --user. De esta manera, puede instalar el paquete solo para el usuario actual.

La documentación dice:

Los archivos se instalarán en subdirectorios del sitio. USER_BASE (escrito como base de usuarios en adelante). Este esquema instala módulos Python puros y módulos de extensión en la misma ubicación (también conocida como site.USER_SITE). Estos son los valores para UNIX, incluido Mac OS X:

Más detalles se pueden encontrar aquí: http://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271241/6999690

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar pip aún sin tener conexión:

En un equipo con conexión te descargas el paquete con todas las dependencias en un directorio:

```sh
$ mkdir wheelhouse
$ pip download -d ./wheelhouse SomePackage
```

Llevas el directorio al equipo sin conexión e instalas:

```sh
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=./wheelhouse SomePackage
```

Si ambos sistemas no son *similares*, también es posible especificar la versión de python y del sistema de los paquetes descargados. Echa un vistazo a la documentación:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/